# Error.java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a recursive program that reads and evaluates fully parenthesized arithmetic expressions. The program was already made, my task is to make the method evaluates recursively. However, I'm having a bit of difficulty doing this. I have gotten much done, but I'm now getting an error - `java.lang.NumberFormatException` - and I can't seem to figure out why and where it's coming from. Could someone please help me as I have been at this for a week and need some help desperately.

Heres my code:

```
    package q2;

    // FILE: EvaluateDemonstration.java
    // This program reads a reads and evaluates fully parenthesized arithmetic
    // expressions.  The purpose is to illustrate a fundamental use of stacks.

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration
    {

        public static void main(String[ ] args)
        {
            Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            String expression;
            double answer;

        System.out.println("Please type an arithmetic expression made from");
        System.out.println("unsigned numbers and the operations + - * /.");
        System.out.println("The expression must be fully parenthesized.");

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Your expression: ");
            expression = stdin.nextLine( );
            try
            {
                answer = evaluate(expression,0,0,0);
                System.out.println("The value is " + answer);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error." + e.toString( ) + " Help");
            }
        }
        while (query(stdin, "Another string?"));

        System.out.println("All numbers are interesting.");
    }


    public static boolean query(Scanner input, String prompt)
    {
        String answer;

        System.out.print(prompt + " [Y or N]: ");
        answer = input.nextLine( ).toUpperCase( );
        while (!answer.startsWith("Y") && !answer.startsWith("N"))
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid response. Please type Y or N: ");
            answer = input.nextLine( ).toUpperCase( );
        }

        return answer.startsWith("Y");
    }


    public static double evaluate(String s, int i,int j, int charIndex)   
    // Precondition: The string is a fully parenthesized arithmetic expression
    // formed from non-negative numbers, parentheses, and the four operations
    // +, -, *, and /.
    // Postcondition: The string has been evaluated and the value returned.
    // Exceptions: Can throw an NumberFormatException if the expression contains
    // characters other than digits, operations, parentheses and whitespace.
    // Can throw IllegalArgumentException if the input line is an
    // illegal expression, such as unbalanced parentheses or a division by zero.
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[3] ;
        Character[] operations = new Character[1];
        String next = "";
        int length = s.length();
        char first;
        int numIndex = i;
        int operatIndex = j;

        if (charIndex < length)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(charIndex))) //|| s.charAt(charIndex) == '.' )
            {
                next += s.charAt(charIndex);
            }
            else
            {

                first = s.charAt(charIndex);

                switch (first)
                {
                case '+': // Addition
                case '-': // Subtraction
                case '*': // Multiplication
                case '/': // Division
                    numbers[numIndex]=(new Double(next));
                    System.out.println(numbers[numIndex]);
                    operations[operatIndex] = first;
                    break;
                case ')': // Right parenthesis
                    evaluateStackTops(numbers, operations);
                    break;
                case '(': // Left parenthesis
                    break;
                default : // Illegal character
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character");
                }
            }
            evaluate(s, ++numIndex, operatIndex+1, charIndex+1);
        }
        if (numbers.length != 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal input expression");

        return numbers[2];
    }


    public static void evaluateStackTops(double[] numbers, Character[] operations)     
    // Precondition: The top of the operations stack contains +, -, *, or /, and
    // the numbers stack contains at least two numbers. 
    // Postcondition: The top two numbers have been popped from the numbers stack, and the
    // top operation has been popped from the operations stack. The two numbers have been
    // combined using the operation (with the second number popped as the left operand). 
    // The result of the operation has then been pushed back onto the numbers stack.
    // Exceptions: Throws an IllegalArgumentException if the stacks are illegal or if the 
    // operation results in a division by zero.
    {
        double operand1, operand2;

        // Check that the stacks have enough items, and get the two operands.
        if ((numbers.length < 2))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal expression");        
        operand2 = numbers[1];
        operand1 = numbers[0];

        // Carry out an action based on the operation on the top of the stack.
        switch (operations[0])
        {
        case '+': numbers[2] = (operand1 + operand2);
        break;
        case '-': numbers[2] = (operand1 - operand2);
        break;
        case '*': numbers[2]= (operand1 * operand2);
        break;
        case '/': // Note: A division by zero results in POSTIVE_INFINITY or
            // NEGATIVE_INFINITY.
            numbers[2] = (operand1 / operand2);
            break;
        default : throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal operation");
        }
    }

    // These patterns are from Appendix B of Data Structures and Other Objects.
    // They may be used in hasNext and findInLine to read certain patterns
    // from a Scanner.
    public static final Pattern CHARACTER =
            Pattern.compile("\\S.*?");  
    public static final Pattern UNSIGNED_DOUBLE =
            Pattern.compile("((\\d+\\.?\\d*)|(\\.\\d+))([Ee][-+]?\\d+)?.*?");
}
```

Here's the trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Double.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at q2.RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.evaluate(RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.java:94) 
at q2.RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.evaluate(RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.java:107) 
at q2.RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.evaluate(RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.java:107) 
at q2.RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.main(RecursiveEvaluateDemonstration.java:29)
```

Comment: Is there no stack trace or line number?

Comment: PLease post your logcat(stack trace)

Comment: logcat? there was no line number in the error, thats why im having trouble solving it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting the number format exception because you're doing

```
            case '+': // Addition
            case '-': // Subtraction
            case '*': // Multiplication
            case '/': // Division
                numbers[numIndex]=(new Double(next));
```

But at this point, the next could be the empty string "", so it will fail with that.

Comment: the program only accepts string formated as (double operator double) ex. (3+4) next would always have a number first.

Comment: Why don't you put a println before that new Double(next) line to see what it's trying to convert.  Which expressions generate that error?

Comment: tried that, and tried adding a println all over the place to see where its going wrong, but as soon as i enter the expression, i get the error. Theres no other output

Comment: Well, I compiled your program and ran it.  Yes the problem is that line.  When it hits the first operator, the next will be empty because the char is an operator (since it's recursive, that operator will be the FIRST char at the index for that particular recursive call).  You need to make next a member instead of a local var.  But then after that there's an array out of bounds error, so look into that next.  Your code is not very clear.  I would write down on paper the algorithm you're using and try to clarify it.  Then do the coding.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to the catch block in the main method and run the program again with same input to receive the stacktrace, then share the stacktrace here.

Comment: As pointed out by Andrew Luo, you are passing an empty string to new Double(next) . What is the input?

Comment: im testing using (3.24+4)

Comment: You are saving 3 to the local variable "next" in the first call to "evaluate" method and trying to access it in the subsequent call to "evaluate" method. The problem is "next" being a local variable is not available to you in the subsequent call to "evaluate" method. Making it a static variable might help you get past this roadblock, but you need to review you logic.

Comment: Here, http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/Java_methods.pdf , you may find this useful.